# get Child of Mirror.Children by index

Tags: swift

I understand I can iterate through the children of a reflected object in swift using foreach...

```
struct demo{

    let b = 2
    let a = 1
    let c = 3




}

let obj = demo()
let reflected = Mirror( reflecting: obj)
let obj = demo()
let reflected = Mirror( reflecting: obj)
for child in reflected.children{
print(child.label)
}
```

Is it possible to access the child by index . Like

```
// refelected.children[index]  this is not a valid syntax
```

How can i access each child by index without using the for loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type `Children` is actually a typedef for `AnyForwardCollection<Child>`.

You can't index into an `AnyForwardCollection` with any old `Int`. You need to use an `AnyForwardIndex`. You can use `startIndex` to get the starting index and `advancedBy()` to move forward.

```
let obj = demo()
let reflected = Mirror( reflecting: obj)

let idx = reflected.children.startIndex
let first = reflected.children[idx]
let thirdIdx = idx.advancedBy(2)
let third = reflected.children[thirdIdx]
```

Answer (score 2):

Further from Kevins answer, I will update slightly for Swift 3.

```
let obj = demo()
let reflected = Mirror(reflecting: obj)
let index: IntMax = 3
let reflectedChildAtIndex = reflected.children.index(reflected.children.startIndex, offsetBy: index, limitedBy: reflected.children.endIndex)
```

Comment: Updated answer based on wider-spider's comment below. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like the answer of Harry Bloom, because it is the most elegant way, but is has a typo: "i" must be **"index"** and I added the line to actually get the item at the given index.

```
let obj = demo()
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: obj)
let index = 3 // careful: max. not checked, just an example
let idx = mirror.children.index(mirror.children.startIndex, offsetBy: index, limitedBy: mirror.children.endIndex)
let valueOfChildAtIndex =  mirror.children[idx!]
```